# Ask setup:static-content:deploy to use more system resources

Tags: magento2

I'm currently running my development on a Windows 10 machine with Laragon.

Php memory limit is set to -1.
8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s).
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16,0 GB.

Still when i run composer or magento upgrade, deploy and compile commands it is really slow. Really irritating.

The question is:
How can i make Magento and Composer use more resources and perform faster? I use so much of my time waiting for these processes and it makes me very sad atm.

Comment: Deployment script uses system disk read/write. So your hard disk speed matters when you apply deployment script

Comment: Are you using any kind of editor like php storm or anything else that run indexing while updating code?

Comment: No php storm and resource monitor shows no peaks in any of the fields.

Running setup:mode:set developer and back to production uses resources:
CPU max 8%, Memory ~300mb and Disk Write Speed: 0-1%

Comment: let's start a step further: when are you calling setup:static-content:deploy? you will never need this when developing. you only need this when deploying.

Comment: 1) Because developer mode is so slow.
2) I'm not a professional
3) I make a lot of mistakes
4) I like to test things

Comment: ok. let me help you out :) read and understand this and you will be able to work a lot faster https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/optimal-dev-environment.html

Comment: I've read those a thousand times. I've set up numerous different environments from live ubuntu to a couple of virtual machines but none of those satisfy me. This is the fastest and lightest set-up so far and has been working very well.

The problem is that none of those uses system resources properly. There are no peaks at all at resource monitor(s).

I'm missing something here and that is what i need to find out. Some setting  or something is wrong by default. If i enable developer mode apache won't use even 10% of my cpu. 50mb memory and so on.

Java works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Develop in **development** mode like suggested in comments:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

This will greatly reduce the amount you need to run **setup upgrade** and **deploy static content**. New modules for example will need a setup upgrade run. Development mode for me is not actually much slower than production when you have atleast some caches running and just turn off what is not needed at the time. For example make sure configs are enabled turn off FPC, static blocks, and layouts and then just do occasional cache flushes if configs change. With that I get relatively decent performance of 2-4 seconds page loads, this is on a Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

The "**Jobs parameter**" can greatly increase atleast the deploying of static content however this does not seem to be available for other Magento CLI tasks.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -j16
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually noticed that developer mode is a bit faster on my local env than before. But this does not answer the original question. Why php does not utilize resources like it should? Maybe it's related to windows?

Comment: I was just showing how to use more threads on the setup:static-content:deploy as  was the main things that you said took a while. Working around having to use those commands I though would help as was making you sad. My ubuntu server is only really using 10-30%. apache will use a thread for each task so 6.25% 16 users simultaneously would knock it up to 100%. Running that command above with all 16 threads should see 100% utilisation if you try it (does for me). It's not designed for each user to throttle your computer a site would just die i guess when more than one user browses a site.